# undock/move Component Tray in Windows Forms Designer

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Working with 16:9 screens, I always have an empty space to my right in Forms Designer.
On the other hand, this Component Tray is always overlapping the forms.
Is there a way to undock or move it to fill that wasted space?
[image: pic showing component-tray overlapping forms designer]

I haven't found any other questions regarding this.
Thank you in advance and please excuse my bad english.

Edited: obviously I know I can drag its edge to fold the thing down.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I created my own Add-In to dock that ComponentTray to the right as well as sorting its components alphabetically.
If you, like me, want to use your wide screen in all its glory, please post a comment below and gladly I'll give you all details.
After the testing phase, I'll upload the thing to VS Gallery.

EDIT: Here's the link to the VS extension. Feel free to use and enjoy it.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f426bc54-af1e-4d7c-9870-94c001f5215d

Best wishes.

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but I downvoted the answer because you didn't give the solution. Answers shouldn't be used for rants or proving a point. They should provide usable solutions to the question.

Comment: well, I'll post a link if I upload the extension to VS gallery. And I edit the answer to remove criticism